# Another WCF No endpoint listening using basicHTTPBinding

Tags: wcf, endpoint, basichttpbinding

I’m no expert on WCF and I’m hoping that someone will point out why my very basic “hello world” WCF service does not work when being tested on separate networked computers using a simple crossover cable. However, It works perfectly when tested on 1 PC. There are NO issues with the 2 PC talking each other as both PC’s can ping each other and both PC’s windows7 firewall has been disabled. Both client and server apps were run using administrator rights.

The server PC has ip of 10.0.0.25

. I have also tested using an adsl modem/switch to network the PC’s, but also had the same results using both Ethernet and wifi connections. It does however  work when I try the exact same scenario on my company’s wireless network which might present a clue.
With the server app running, from the client PC, I open web browser and I enter the following URL. This indicates that the service is running.

```
http://10.0.0.25:1235/MySecondService
```

It works when I test the same scenario with both client and server running on 1 PC.

ERROR:
There was no endpoint listening at `http://10.0.0.25:1235/MySecondService` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Client Program.cs

```
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string serviceURL = "http://10.0.0.25:1235/MySecondService";

      ChannelFactory<IMySecondService> channelFactory1 =
          new ChannelFactory<IMySecondService>(
              new BasicHttpBinding(),
              new EndpointAddress(serviceURL));

      IMySecondService mySecondService = channelFactory1.CreateChannel();

      Console.WriteLine("This test console application is a client for the MyFirstService WCF service");
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("It tries to use the service at address: {0}", serviceURL));
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.Write("Write text to get number of words: ");

      string s = Console.ReadLine();
      int numberWords = mySecondService.GetNumberWords(s);

      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Number of words: {0}", numberWords));

      s = Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Client App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMySecondService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://10.0.0.25:1235/MySecondService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMySecondService" contract="ServiceReference1.IMySecondService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IMySecondService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Server Program.cs

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      ServiceHost serviceHost1 = new ServiceHost(typeof(MySecondService));

      serviceHost1.Open();

      Console.WriteLine("This console application hosts the MySecondService WCF service at address " +  serviceHost1. BaseAddresses[0]. ToString());      

      Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to finish hosting");
      Console.ReadLine();

      serviceHost1.Close();
    }
  }
```

Server App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SecondService.MySecondService"
               behaviorConfiguration="">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://10.0.0.25:1235/MySecondService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="SecondService.IMySecondService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>    
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>       
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it works on one of the networks you tried (your work network) and not on your home network my guess is the IP Address you are using is valid only on that network. When you are on other networks such as your home wifi you may be using a different NIC and/or being assigned a different IP. Try going to a command line in windows and checking your IP Addresses for all NICs with this command

```
ipconfig -all
```

Comment: When I swopped between networks the IP adresses did change due to the DHCP. I did make the relevant changes in the code to accomodate this. Also when swoping between the 2 networks, I only used the wifi ports to make sure that the differences between the 2 test remain as little as possible

Comment: I've managed to figure this out. It was a proxy setting in Internet explorer that was giving me all this grieve. My companys netork uses a proxy server to access the internet. I normally use mozilla firefox to access the internet. So when I swop between networks I change the proxy settings within firefox and i am able to access the internet. It looks like WCF uses the settings of "Internet Explorer" and obviously this settings wasn't changing while I was swopping between different networks. So bottom line make sure that proxy seetings in IE is correct when using WCF.